# Convert selected DropDownChoice to Model in CompoundPropertyModel

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

Is it possible, in a Wicket way, to convert the selected DropDownChoices value, when the form has a CompoundPropertyModel attached with a Model, which has another type for the specific attribute.

Simple example, because i guess my explanation isn't very accurate:

```
public enum MyChoices {
    ONE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3);
    // ... etc
}

public class MyEntityModel {
    private int number;
    private String text;
}

// the WebPages constructor:
public ChoicePage() {
    IModel<MyEntityModel> model = new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new EntityModel());
    Form<MyEntityModel> form = new Form<MyEntityModel>("form", model);
    add(form);

    form.add(new TextField<String>("text"));
    form.add(new DropDownChoice<>("choices", Model.of(MyChoices.ONE),
             Arrays.asList(MyChoices.values()))

}
```

When submitting the form with ONE selected, i want the model object to have the value `1`.

I do know, that i could name the DropDownChoice component other than the MyEntityModel field and copy it's value into the model after submit. But that is not Wickets model approach, is it?

P.s.: I'm using Wicket 6.17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do some conversion.

Either convert the list of choices:

```
form.add(new DropDownChoice<Integer>("number",
  new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<Integer>>() {
    public List<Integer> getObject() {
      return MyChoices.getAllAsInts();
    }
  }
);
```

or the selected choice:

```
form.add(new DropDownChoice<MyChoices>("number", Arrays.asList(MyChoices.values()) {
  public IModel<?> initModel() {
    final IModel<Integer> model = (IModel<Integer>)super.initModel();

    return new IModel<MyChoice>() {
      public MyChoice getObject() {
        return MyChoice.fromInt(model.getObject());
      }

      public void setObject(MyChoice myChoice) {
        model.setObject(myChoice.toInt());
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: The second solution was exactly what i was looking for. It's only flaw is the unchecked cast, which i try to avoid typically.